# HTTP Request inside Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am wondering if it is possible to make a background http request inside a live wallpaper (android service).

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by casual? You mean background? Might be an opinion, but background http requests sound like malware to me.

Comment: f.e. I would like to read weather data and change my live wallpaper depending on weather condition.

Answer (score 2):

A live wallpaper is very similar to a normal Android application and has access to all the facilities of the platform. That includes network access.

Comment: so you mean if I try something like this it should be no problem?try
         {
          HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.yahoo.com");

          HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

          if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
          {
           str = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
          }
         }catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
         }

Comment: Only one way to find out, right? Make sure you set the right permissions for your application.

Comment: this is the solution: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> thanks!